# Translating two C++ functions to Pascal

Tags: c++, pascal, freepascal, translate

I can't seem to understand why my translation doesn't give the desired result. Here's the C++ source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int minint(int candidate = -1) {
  if (candidate - 1 >= 0)
    return candidate;
  for (int stride = -1, stride2 = 2*stride; ; stride = stride2, stride2 += stride2)
    if (stride2 >= 0 || candidate + stride2 >= 0)
      return minint(candidate + stride);
}

int maxint(int candidate = 1) {
  if (candidate + 1 <= 0)
    return candidate;
  for (int stride = 1, stride2 = 2*stride; ; stride = stride2, stride2 += stride2)
    if (stride2 <= 0 || candidate + stride2 <= 0)
      return maxint(candidate + stride);
}

int main() {
  (void) printf("Max int is %d\n", maxint());
  (void) printf("Min int is %d\n", minint());
  return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
Max int is 2147483647
Min int is -2147483648
```

And here's the Pascal code (compiled using Free Pascal):

```
program Translation;

function minint (candidate : Longint) : Longint;
    var stride, stride2 : Longint;
    var bool : Boolean;
    begin
        bool := false;
        if (candidate - 1) >= 0 then
        begin
            bool := true;
            minint := candidate;
        end;
        if (bool = false) then
        begin
            stride := -1;
            stride2 := 2*stride;
            while (stride2 < 0) and (candidate + stride2 < 0) do
            begin
                stride := stride2;
                stride2 += stride2;
            end;
            minint := minint(candidate + stride)
        end;
    end;

function maxint (candidate : Longint) : Longint;
    var stride, stride2 : Longint;
    var bool : Boolean;
    begin
        bool := false;
        if (candidate + 1) <= 0 then
        begin
            bool := true;
            maxint := candidate;
        end;
        if (bool = false) then
        begin
            stride := 1;
            stride2 := 2*stride;
            while (stride2 > 0) and (candidate + stride2 > 0) do
            begin
                stride := stride2;
                stride2 += stride2;
            end;
            maxint := minint(candidate + stride)
        end;
    end;

begin
    writeln(maxint(1));
    writeln(minint(-1));
end.
```

Which for some reason prints:

```
1073741825
2147483647
```

Very, very odd. The 'maxint' value is approximately half of what it needs to be, and the 'minint' value is positive (actually, it's what the 'maxint' value is supposed to be).

What am I missing? Bear in mind that I am prohibited from using sequencers (that is, commands such as Exit - hence the boolean) and default arguments.

Comment: Your C++ version looks pretty wrong too...

Comment: It looks like the C++ code is using undefined behaviour with arithmetic overflow/underflow on signed integers (I'm not absolutely sure about that — it is contorted code at best).  Pascal will do things differently.

Comment: Yes, that C++ version is wrong. It may work with some compilers. (Perhaps even most.) But at least two major current compilers compile it in a way that makes it absolutely not do what you want. With GCC, it gets compiled to an infinite loop. With clang, the printed max int is negative and the printed min int is positive. @JonathanLeffler The UB it has is indeed signed integer overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Sadly, the C++ code is what I was supplied with. It's a given. There's no point trying to change it, although I wholeheartedly agree it is highly obscure. 

There is an equivalent Pascal code out there. It should be mainly based on these broken C++ functions. Any way I can overcome the deliberate flaws of the original functions?

Comment: `it is highly obscure` It isn't just obscure, it's definitely wrong, even if it prints the correct result on your computer with your compiler. While this doesn't help you, it says something about your teacher (etc.) ...

Comment: `Low(Integer)` and `High(Integer)` is not enough BTW?

Comment: Even the standard says in 5/4 "Note: most existing implementations of C++
ignore integer overflows." I remember Stroustrup (or was it K&R?) saying something along the lines "the result should not come as a surprise if you know the hardware architecture". Yes, it may throw on some exotic hardware. Anybody have access to one as an example? Nobody? So I think it's a reasonable assignment which teaches you about integer representations and recursive algorithms in a fairly elegant way. Yes, one should mention that it is strictly UB, and then get stuff done.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Not only the hardware is a problem, but compiler optimizations. The compiler may assume there is no UB in the code and produce wrong optimized code if there is. And yes, latter cases exist in real life even on "normal" hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DO NOT** rely on underflow/overflow behaviour in C++.  It is undefined.
Instead, use the limits library to determine your integer size limitations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::min() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

In Pascal, a `LongInt` has a fixed size.
You can rely on it being 4 bytes long.

---

In regards to your Pascal code, you have a typo in your "maxint" function.

The line:

```
maxint := minint(candidate + stride)
```

should be:

```
maxint := maxint(candidate + stride)
```

Comment: (actually, the question is about `int`)

Comment: Thanks, but my task wasn't to write the C++ code, nor to find the numeric limits of the types. I was asked to translate the given C++ code to Pascal. Any help with finding my error in the translation would be appreciated.

Comment: @deviantfan ok, changed to int. The pascal example uses LongInt instead of Integer which seems incongruous.

Comment: @JeanFrancoisClout The C++ code returns fixed values. Find the values, and you can accurately translate it to a Pascal one-liner. Or do you want to make your Pascal code exhibit the same unpredictable behaviour depending on the compiler used and the optimisation level? (I'm not blaming you for the bad question, I realise you're not in control of that, but that still doesn't make it a good question.)

Comment: @hvd The code should exhibit the same intended behaviour, which is to find the numeric limit of a given type. Those C++ functions were written by the TAs of a course I'm taking. I believe their goal was to show that converting these functions to Pascal will make for a more verbose code. The problem is apparently much deeper than I thought. Question is, how did the TAs succeed in writing an equivalent program in Pascal, which actually works?

Comment: @JeanFrancoisClout The assignment is ridiculous because they've given you an undefined algorithm in C++, and you would never want to do this in Pascal.  Nonetheless, your actual problem is in your "maxint" function where you call maxint := minint(candidate + stride) instead of maxint := maxint(candidate + stride).  Here is the fixed version:  https://ideone.com/8itUZg

Comment: @TrevorHickey Thanks! It did the trick. I'll make sure all complaints about this horrific piece of code will be heard, for the sake of future generations.

Comment: @TrevorHickey (first comment): longint is 32-bit integer independent of language mode. Integer is 16-bit or 32-bit depending on mode(but regardless of architecture) So that is not wrong/unwise unless you explicitly target 16-bit mode (where it would be a slowdown). It will work with both FPC and Delphi, the only Pascal(derived) compilers in use nowadays

Comment: This has almost no connection to the OP's problem (which was, obviously, not to find max int. One doesn't need a program for that).

Answer (score 0):

This, IMO rather literal translation (but without using `Break`, `Continue` or `Exit`) works for me (Note: Delphi, not FPC, but I guess there is a compatible mode for that in FPC):

```
{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}
{$RANGECHECKS OFF}
function minint(candidate: Integer = -1): Integer;
var
  stride: Integer;
  stride2: Integer;
begin
  if candidate - 1 >= 0 then
    minint := candidate
  else
  begin
    stride := -1;
    stride2 := 2 * stride;
    while (stride2 < 0) and (candidate + stride2 < 0) do
    begin
      stride := stride2;
      stride2 := stride2 + stride2;
    end;
    minint := minint(candidate + stride);
  end;
end;
```

It produces the following output:

```
Min int is -2147483648
```

I did not translate maxint, but I guess you can do that yourself.

It looks quite like your translation (but without the bool).